# Why is the route correct but still giving 404 error on Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-errors

I got a 404 error on my website when accessing the correct route, did I do something wrong

**urls.py handles the main route**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'api/facebook/(.+?)', include('apifacebooks.urls')),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('getcookie', include('app.urls')),
    path('change-lang', include('app.urls')),
    re_path(r'auth/(.+?)', include('app.urls')),
]
```

**urls.py handles routes in the apifacebooks app**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/facebook/like-post',views.like_post)
]
```

And when I go to `http://localhost:8000/api/facebook/like-post` I get a 404 error

[Image error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZahO.png)

**My question has been solved, thanks**

Comment: Try with trailing slash like `http://localhost:8000/api/facebook/like-post/`

Comment: @Bairavan It still doesn't work

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: @Razenstein I added the error image in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your apifacebooks app change the path because you had "api..." double in the path

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('like-post/',views.like_post)
]
```

And in the root urls.py just

```
path('api/facebook/', ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the url pattern would be "`http://localhost:8000/api/facebook/api/facebook/like-post`".
As explained id [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs-1):

> Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of
> the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the
> included URLconf for further processing.

Remove "`api/facebook/`" in "apifacebooks.urls", for example:

Main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'api/facebook/(.+?)/', include('apifacebooks.urls')),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('getcookie', include('app.urls')),
    path('change-lang', include('app.urls')),
    re_path(r'auth/(.+?)', include('app.urls')),
]
```

apifacebooks.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('like-post',views.like_post)
]
```

Or you can try to place remove "`r'api/facebook/(.+?)'`", for example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('apifacebooks.urls')),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('getcookie', include('app.urls')),
    path('change-lang', include('app.urls')),
    re_path(r'auth/(.+?)', include('app.urls')),
]
```